# jQuery Events only apply to last element

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

This is a bit of a tricky one. I am building a Carousel view, which gets hooked up at loadtime using jQuery.

Here is the mark-up:

```
<div class="carousel" data-direction="v" id="carousel1">
    <div class="card-cont">
        <div id="card1" class="card">This is Card 1</div>
        <div id="card2" class="card">This is Card 2</div>
        <div id="card3" class="card">This is Card 3</div>
        <div id="card4" class="card">This is Card 4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel" data-direction="h" id="carousel2">
    <div class="card-cont">
        <div id="card5" class="card">This is Card 1</div>
        <div id="card6" class="card">This is Card 2</div>
        <div id="card7" class="card">This is Card 3</div>
        <div id="card8" class="card">This is Card 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I loop through all `.carousel` elements and hook up the functionality. The code is object-oriented, and I have posted some jsFiddle here > http://jsfiddle.net/eZbUB/

The problem is that whenever I have more than one carousel on a page, the events (i.e. changing card) only get applied to the LAST carousel on the page. Does anyone have a solution? The positioning functions for the indicator and sizing etc. all work fine. Here is the full jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').each(function() { Carousel.init($(this)); });
});

var Carousel = {

    container       : null,
    card_container  : null,
    cards           : [ ],
    card_width      : 0,
    no_cards        : 0,
    indicator       : { },
    current_card    : 0,
    direction       : 'h',

    init : function(container) {

        // Assin vars:
        var self             = this;
        this.container       = container;
        this.card_container  = this.container.find('.card-cont');
        this.cards           = this.container.find('div.card');
        this.card_width      = this.container.width();
        this.no_cards        = this.cards.length;
        this.direction       = $(this.container).attr('data-direction');

        // Size the container:
        this.card_container.width((this.card_width * this.no_cards))

        // Add an indicator:
        this.indicator = $('<ul class="card-indicator" />');
        this.indicator.items = [ ];

        if(this.direction == 'v') { this.indicator.addClass('vertical'); }

        for(var i = 0; i < this.no_cards; i++)
        {
            $(this.cards[i]).width(this.card_width);
            var indicator_item = $('<li />');
            indicator_item.click(function() { self.setCard($(this).index()); });
            this.indicator.append(indicator_item);
            this.indicator.items.push(indicator_item);

        }
        this.indicator.appendTo(this.container);

        // Position the indicator:
        if(this.direction == 'h')
        {
            var indicator_top_pos = ((this.container.offset().top + this.container.height()) - this.indicator.height());
            var indicator_left_pos = (this.container.width() - this.indicator.width()) / 2;
            this.indicator.css({ top: indicator_top_pos, left: indicator_left_pos });
        }
        else
        {
            var indicator_top_pos = (this.container.height() - this.indicator.height()) / 2;
            var indicator_left_pos = (this.container.offset().left + this.container.width()) - 20;
            this.indicator.css({ top: indicator_top_pos, left: indicator_left_pos });
        }

        // Add the current styles to everything:
        $(this.cards[0]).addClass('current');
        this.indicator.items[0].addClass('current');

        // Hook up the drag events:
        var mouse_start_x = 0;
        var mouse_end_x   = 0;
        var mouse_start_y = 0;
        var mouse_end_y   = 0;
        var direction_x   = null;
        var direction_y   = null;
        var next_index    = 0;

        this.container.mousedown(function(e) {
            mouse_start_x = e.pageX;
            mouse_start_y = e.pageY;
        });
        this.container.mouseup(function(e) {
            mouse_end_x = e.pageX;
            mouse_end_y = e.pageY;

            alert(self.container.attr('id'));

            if(mouse_end_x > mouse_start_x) { direction_x = 'right'; }
            if(mouse_end_x < mouse_start_x) { direction_x = 'left'; }
            if(mouse_end_y > mouse_start_y) { direction_y = 'down'; }
            if(mouse_end_y < mouse_start_y) { direction_y = 'up'; }

            switch(self.direction)
            {
                case 'v':
                    if(direction_y == 'down') { next_index = (self.current_card == 0) ? 0 : self.current_card - 1; }
                    if(direction_y == 'up')   { next_index = (self.current_card == (self.no_cards - 1)) ? self.current_card : self.current_card + 1; }
                    break;

                case 'h':
                default:
                    if(direction_x == 'right') { next_index = (self.current_card == (self.no_cards - 1)) ? self.current_card : self.current_card + 1; }
                    if(direction_x == 'left')  { next_index = (self.current_card == 0) ? 0 : self.current_card - 1; }
                    break;
            }
            self.setCard(next_index);
        });

        // Return the object (we use init as a constructor):
        return this;
    },

    // Function to check if we're on the last card:
    onLastCard : function() {
        return (this.current_card == (this.indicator.items.length - 1)) ? true : false;
    },

    // Function to check if we're on the first card:
    onFirstCard : function() {
        return (this.current_card == 0) ? true : false;
    },

    setCard : function(index) {
        // If the index matches the current one, don't do anything:
        if(index == this.current_card)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Calculate the left position we need to move:
            var new_left_pos = this.card_width * index;
            this.card_container.css({ left: -new_left_pos });
            this.indicator.items[this.current_card].removeClass('current');
            this.indicator.items[index].addClass('current');
            this.current_card = index;
            return true;
        }
    },
};
```

I have tried other alternatives (such as `bind()` and `live()`, but neither has worked). Any help most gratefully received.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I have added in the full jQuery code to the question, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're calling `Carousel.init`, within `init` function `this` will always be `Carousel` — that is, there's only one. That's why you're only seeing it get applied to the last.

I'd look at reworking `Carousel` to be a *constructor function* (the kind you use with `new`). @Boo has just thrown a `new` in front of `Carousel.init`, which is a good start, but the object being created won't have the various properties you've put on `Carousel`.

Here's a quick reworking; it's completely untested, but should take you in the right direction:

```
// Scoping function so our various member functions can have proper names
var Carousel = (function() {

    // The constructor function    
    function Carousel() {
        // Assign vars:
        var self             = this; // Important for the event handler closures

        this.container       = container;
        this.card_container  = this.container.find('.card-cont');
        this.cards           = this.container.find('div.card');
        this.card_width      = this.container.width();
        this.no_cards        = this.cards.length;
        this.direction       = $(this.container).attr('data-direction');

        // Size the container:
        this.card_container.width((this.card_width * this.no_cards))

        // Add an indicator:
        this.indicator = $('<ul class="card-indicator" />');
        this.indicator.items = [ ];

        if(this.direction == 'v') { this.indicator.addClass('vertical'); }

        for(var i = 0; i < this.no_cards; i++)
        {
            $(this.cards[i]).width(this.card_width);
            var indicator_item = $('<li />');
            indicator_item.click(function() { self.setCard($(this).index()); });
            this.indicator.append(indicator_item);
            this.indicator.items.push(indicator_item);

        }
        this.indicator.appendTo(this.container);

        // Position the indicator:
        if(this.direction == 'h')
        {
            var indicator_top_pos = ((this.container.offset().top + this.container.height()) - this.indicator.height());
            var indicator_left_pos = (this.container.width() - this.indicator.width()) / 2;
            this.indicator.css({ top: indicator_top_pos, left: indicator_left_pos });
        }
        else
        {
            var indicator_top_pos = (this.container.height() - this.indicator.height()) / 2;
            var indicator_left_pos = (this.container.offset().left + this.container.width()) - 20;
            this.indicator.css({ top: indicator_top_pos, left: indicator_left_pos });
        }

        // Add the current styles to everything:
        $(this.cards[0]).addClass('current');
        this.indicator.items[0].addClass('current');

        // Hook up the drag events:
        var mouse_start_x = 0;
        var mouse_end_x   = 0;
        var mouse_start_y = 0;
        var mouse_end_y   = 0;
        var direction_x   = null;
        var direction_y   = null;
        var next_index    = 0;

        this.container.mousedown(function(e) {
            mouse_start_x = e.pageX;
            mouse_start_y = e.pageY;
        });
        this.container.mouseup(function(e) {
            mouse_end_x = e.pageX;
            mouse_end_y = e.pageY;

            alert(self.container.attr('id'));

            if(mouse_end_x > mouse_start_x) { direction_x = 'right'; }
            if(mouse_end_x < mouse_start_x) { direction_x = 'left'; }
            if(mouse_end_y > mouse_start_y) { direction_y = 'down'; }
            if(mouse_end_y < mouse_start_y) { direction_y = 'up'; }

            switch(self.direction)
            {
                case 'v':
                    if(direction_y == 'down') { next_index = (self.current_card == 0) ? 0 : self.current_card - 1; }
                    if(direction_y == 'up')   { next_index = (self.current_card == (self.no_cards - 1)) ? self.current_card : self.current_card + 1; }
                    break;

                case 'h':
                default:
                    if(direction_x == 'right') { next_index = (self.current_card == (self.no_cards - 1)) ? self.current_card : self.current_card + 1; }
                    if(direction_x == 'left')  { next_index = (self.current_card == 0) ? 0 : self.current_card - 1; }
                    break;
            }
            self.setCard(next_index);
        });

        // No need to return `this`, that's what constructor functions do by default
    }

    // Our various member functions, we'll assign them to the prototype below

    // Function to check if we're on the last card:
    function Carousel$onLastCard() {
        return (this.current_card == (this.indicator.items.length - 1)) ? true : false;
    }

    // Function to check if we're on the first card:
    function Carousel$onFirstCard() {
        return (this.current_card == 0) ? true : false;
    }

    function Carousel$setCard(index) {
        // If the index matches the current one, don't do anything:
        if(index == this.current_card)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Calculate the left position we need to move:
            var new_left_pos = this.card_width * index;
            this.card_container.css({ left: -new_left_pos });
            this.indicator.items[this.current_card].removeClass('current');
            this.indicator.items[index].addClass('current');
            this.current_card = index;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Fill in the prototype that will be assigned to all objects created
    // via `new Carousel`:

    Carousel.prototype.onLastCard = Carousel$onLastCard;
    Carousel.prototype.onFirstCard = Carousel$onFirstCard;
    Carousel.prototype.setCard = Carousel$setCard;

    // Return our constructor out of the scoping function to be assigned
    // to the public var    
    return Carousel;

})();
```

And then use is:

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').each(function() { new Carousel($(this)); });
});
```

Again, the above is not meant to be perfect, done, and dusted. It's to demonstrate how you reformulate `Carousel` as a *constructor function* and set up functions on its prototype so they get assigned to the instances created via `new Carousel`. There will be some debugging required. I'm pleased to see you're already handling the issue of `this` within event handlers (via your `self` variable in what used to be `init` and is now the `Carousel` function).

Some possibly helpful reading:

- [Anonymouses anonymous](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) -- explains why I've used a scoping function and real, named functions in the above
- [Simple, Efficient Supercalls in JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html) -- a discussion of creating constructor functions (I've called them "classes" but I really shouldn't have, I've been meaning to update the article) and some utilities for making it easier, as well as enabling hierarchies if you need them

Comment: Thanks for your precious assistance @T.J.Crowder - that is a fantastic solution and with a little editing, I managed to get it working great. I also really enjoyed reading over to the two Articles you have shared.

Comment: @BenM: Good deal, glad that helped! Oh, this one might also be useful: [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html). (It helps explain why `this` was always `Carousel` originally.) Best,

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over the carousel divs, create a new Carousel object every time:

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').each(function() { new Carousel.init($(this)); });
});
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/4nbYR/

Comment: Thanks @Boo. Creating a new Carousel object each time now produces the following error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'setCard'`, even though everything else seems to relate accordingly. Any tips?

Comment: @BenM: That's because the object created by `new Carousel.init` has a blank prototype (because there's nothing on `Carousel.init.prototype`), but your code assumes it will have the functions you've put on the `Carousel` object. What you really want is a proper constructor function, I've done a quick (untested) example of what it might look like in my answer.